# Load wiremock stub files

Tags: cucumber-jvm, wiremock

I wanted to load all my wiremock stub files before start-up my cucumber-jvm tests.

As per wiremock [docs](http://wiremock.org/docs/api/) via API only one file can be pushed. Not bulk. I was think using java code within the test project before kick-off tests.

Whats would be the best way of doing this through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling wiremock api you can upload multiple stubs in one go as per below solution.

[Solution](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/987#issuecomment-626585971)

> Try POSTing it to http://localhost:8080/__admin/mappings/import