# Wiremock - Multiple stubs in one file

Tags: wiremock

I'm trying to group multiple stubs into one JSON file.

I've already ready read this post :
[Load wiremock stub files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519644/load-wiremock-stub-files)
and this one  https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/987https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/987

but I still can't make it work.

Currently, I have the following class:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0, stubs = "classpath:/stubs/mappings", files = "classpath:/stubs")
public class ConfigurationTest {

@Autowired
  protected WireMockServer wireMockServer;

}
```

In my `test/java/resources` folder, I have :

`mappings` folder with different stubs

I'd like to have one file that contains all the stubs in the `mappings`.

I tried to create a `.json` file under `mappings` as below :

```json
{
  "mappings" : [{
    
   ]}
}
```

but i get the following exception

```
Unrecognized field "mappings" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.StubMapping), not marked as ignorable
```

If I try a json that starts an array, I also have an exception

Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token at

Do you have any idea on how to resolve this issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you on the latest WireMock version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `mappings` is not a recognized field by WireMock when the server starts up. Essentially, when WireMock starts up and looks in the `mappings/` directory, it expects each mapping to be a separate file. There are certain fields that WireMock accepts as valid, and `mappings` is not one of them. You can only add multiple mappings via a `mappings` array when doing a `POST` to the WireMock server.

Your options are:

- Have multiple mappings files in the `mappings/` directory, so that WireMock automatically registers these mappings on startup
- After starting the WireMock server with no mappings, doing a `POST` to `/__admin/mappings/import` with your `mappings` array as the payload ([source](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/987#issuecomment-626585971))

I think I would suggest having distinct mappings files in the `mappings/` directory. It allows for a more clear separation of what calls you have mappings for.